# iPhone + NSUserDefault + NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

I am trying to save a MutableArray in NSUserDefault as follows:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:arrSelectedPlayers forKey:@"arrSelectedPlayers"];
```

Than I am trying to get this array:

```
arrSelectedPlayers =  [[prefs mutableArrayValueForKey:@"arrSelectedPlayers"] mutableCopy];
```

But I am not getting back my array.

Please help.

Regards,
Pratik

Answer (score 1):

After setting the mutable array into the user prefers, you need to `synchronize` the user defaults object to write the preferences to disk. I'm assuming that your read of the array occurs after the app has restarted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code slightly:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:arrSelectedPlayers forKey:@"arrSelectedPlayers"];
[prefs synchronize];
```